# Linux bash: how to replace 2 words in a file from bash command line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to replace 2 words in a file from Bash command line, for example:
fileA.txt

```
xxxx AA BB xxx
```

I need to replace "AA BB" from Bash command line with "CC DD", so the file would become:

```
xxxx CC DD xxx
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is a "word"? The solution you accepted will only work for some definitions of the term but will not work in general for space-separated or punctuation-separated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `sed` command,

```
sed -i 's/AA BB/CC DD/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'xxxx AA BB xxx' | sed 's/AA BB/CC DD/g'
xxxx CC DD xxx
```

And through awk,

```
awk '{sub(/AA BB/,"CC DD")}1' infile > outfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'xxxx AA BB xxx' | awk '{sub(/AA BB/,"CC DD")}1'
xxxx CC DD xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/AA BB/CC DD/g' t.txt > new.txt
```

The command works as

sed -e 's/TEXT_TO_REPLACE/NEW_TEXT/g' filename.txt > output.txt